# Faceted barplots rpy/ggplot2 - cannot make it work, only get one

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, rpy2, facet

This question is about ggplot2 in rpy2, but I will accept answers in R, if that is easier for you. I'll happily translate the solution afterwards.

I have a rpy2 dataframe that looks like the following (full file [here](http://pastebin.com/Pf7DwQjA)):

```
    times_seen nb_timepoints main_island other_timepoint

1            0             2           0               0
2          346             2           0               3
3          572             2           0               6
4          210             2           0               9
5          182             2           0              12
6          186             2           0              18
7          212             2           0              21
8          346             2           3               0
...
```

For each `main_island` and `nb_timepoints` I want to plot all the `other_timepoint`s with their respective values.

I have the following code:

```
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2
import rpy2.robjects as ro

p = ggplot2.ggplot(rpy2_df) + ggplot2.aes_string(y='times_seen', x='other_timepoint') + ggplot2.geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I'd like to get something like what is shown in the image below, how do I achieve that?

Ps. I've appended a file that shows approx what I want to achieve (only that I want grids, labels, axes, etc.)

[image]

Comment: The code is working, forgot to print after adding the facets.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your plot:

```
p + ggplot2.facet_grid(ro.Formula('nb_timepoints ~ main_island'))
```

This produces a graph like:

[image]